# Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно. (python 3)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, windows-service

Создал скрипт, который по идеи реализует службу windows:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
from multiprocessing import Process

import helloworld


class Service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
     _svc_name_ = "TestService"
     _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"
     _svc_description_ = "Tests Python service framework by receiving and echoing 
 messages over a named pipe"

def __init__(self, *args):
    super().__init__(*args)

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    self.process.terminate()
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

def SvcDoRun(self):
    self.process = Process(target=self.main)
    self.process.start()
    self.process.run()


def main(self):
    helloworld.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

[image: Вывод консоли]

Дебаг отлично отрабатывает))[image: дебаг]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в поиске библиотек службой, в системных переменных дописал в Path:

```
    D:\Programms\Python3.6.2\Lib\site-packages\pypiwin32_system32
    D:\Programms\Python3.6.2\Lib\site-packages\win32
```